# Why heap corruption when returning an object Mat?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, heap-corruption

I don't understand why I get a corrupted heap error with this program (I'm using OpenCV for the class `Mat`):

```
class A {
    private:
    Mat image;      

    static UINT ThreadProc( LPVOID pParam ) {
        A* pThis= (ClientNetwork*)pParam;
        UINT nRet= pThis->DoThreadProc();     // get out of 'static mode'
        return( nRet );
    }
    UINT ClientNetwork::DoThreadProc() {
         vector<uchar> vect;
         while(1) {
             /**** initialize vect and get the image data to decode ****/

             decode(vect);
         }
    }

    public:
    void decode(const vector<uchar>& vectorData){image=imdecode(vectorData, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);}
    Mat get_image(){return image;}
    void start() {m_pcThread= AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc, this );}
}

int main() {
    A* a = new A();
    a->start();
    while(1) {
        Mat image = a->get_image();
    }
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the error come from `Mat image = a->get_image();` because if I return a reference instead of a copy of the object, I don't have error anymore:

```
Mat* get_image(){return &image;}
```

and

```
Mat* image = a->get_image();
```

I read that returning a copy of an object is more elegant in C++ than a reference. So I would like to know what is wrong.

EDIT: Visual studio breaks at `a->decode(vect)` but it happens only when I return an object and not a reference.

EDIT 2: 
I edited the code to reflect the full program. I think the problem comes from the shared object `a` which is copy and modified at the same time. I will see if the problem still occur using a mutex.

Comment: Take the `vector<uchar>` by reference or a const-reference.

Comment: @Ajay I still have the error. Passing by reference avoid the copy but it is deleted at the end of `decode`, right ?

Comment: That wasn't answer, but recommendation.

Comment: @Ajay ok, I edited my code to take into account your recommendation.

Comment: Is imdecode returning an empty matrix after you call decode with a null vector?

Comment: The thing with heap corruption is that it could be happening *deep* down, but apparent somewhere else.

imdecode seems to take a memory buffer as input and decodes the image as stored in memory. You are passing an uinitialized vector of bytes to that function. That could be the error. Pass something valid.

Comment: @crazylpfan yes, if I put Null as parameter of imdecode, the function return an empty matrix.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal yes, I will edit the code to reflect the full program, I think the problem is from somewhere else because I'm using several threads without mutex (!!!). So the copy and then decode must interact and throw an error but not with the reference as it is just the address. I was not looking at the correct place.

Comment: I will still say what I said above - imdecode expects a buffer of memory as input. What you passed in is a unitialized vector. Pass a initialized 'buffer' of bytes; the kind that imdecode expects. That buffer needs to point to a valid memory address AND contain what the imdecode expects; there should be in there somewhere in the structure of buffer of bytes to say that the buffer is empty. You yourself said that the problem goes away when you pass in NULL; NULL signals to imdecode that there is no memory buffer.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal Ah my fault, I was not enough explicit in the code above. The vector is inialized and has correct data. I can correctly decode the image without problem. That's what i meabt by`// get the vector of data`. I will change that right now.

Comment: Modify the function `get_image` as `Mat get_image(){return image.clone();}`

Comment: @sgar91 why returning a clone instead a copy of the image works ? A clone is a also a copy of the Mat.

Comment: @Seltymar is my suggestion working?

Comment: @sgar91 yes it is. And I don't understand why. I hope you can explain me :).

Comment: Thats because, when you simply `return image;`, the return value is just a reference to the original `image`. And when you `return image.clone()`, it returns a deep copy of the `image`.

Comment: @sgar91 I see, the copy-constructor doesn't make a deep copy. You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy constructor of `cv::Mat` does not create a deep copy of the image. It just creates a reference to the original `Mat` and increases its reference count.
In the following function of the class, the `return` statement calls the copy constructor, returning a reference to the original `image`, which is the probable cause of heap corruption:

```
Mat get_image(){ return image; }
```

You should return a deep copy of the `image` as follows, so that the original `image` does not get modified accidentally.

```
Mat get_image(){ return image.clone(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `a` without initialising it.

```
int main() {
    A* a;
    vector<uchar> vect;
    while(1) {
        // get the vector of data
        a->decode(vect);
```

Welcome to undefined behaviour, population: you.

Initialise `a` for a better result.

Comment: My bad, I correct it right now. The thing is why I get a heap corruption because I return an object.

Answer (score 2):

Then that is the thread sync problem, as you yourself suggested. The image is being constantly filled in in that infinite while loop. And in the middle of it somewhere you try to make a copy of it. Recipe for disaster. You need to take a write lock inside that loop in DoThreadProc, in each iteration. And then you need to take a read lock inside your get_image. You need to use a read/write lock library that does not starve out readers.

Alternatively you could work with mutexes/critical sections. Both that write loop, and that read (get_image) just get exclusive access to image while they are doing their work.

I am curious though - your thread procedure is decoding things in an infinite loop. What are you trying to do in there? And while reading what image do you expect? Any image at that point of time in loop iteration?

Comment: I want to use mutex from c++11 but it is not implemented in vs2010... (Maybe I'm going to use boost) Actually, the part where I get the data and initialize my vector is a network part. I have the main thread for the UI and one for the network. I have several solutions like using asynchronized or non-blocking sockets. I'm not sure I used the best one.

Comment: since when did mutexes go away from windows development? Granted that recent versions of VS might make it more difficult to use native win library, but they are still there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 

And as I said, it is best to use a class that implements read and write locks. Jeffery Richter, the guy who wrote windows programming books, has one for years now. http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/slip0102A/people/jcxb/code/SWMRG_8cpp-source.html

Comment: I tried with the mutex, but I still have the problem. What @sgar91 point out in comment works. I'm waiting from him to get more explanation.